# How to write a condition in python to only remove duplicates that have 2 and more duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, conditional-statements

I have a dataset that has duplicates of Product IDs. However, I would only like to remove all the duplicates that have a value 'No' from column 'Translation' - so far, I have this:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset="Product ID ")
```

However, I need to add the condition to only removed those Product IDs that repeat more than twice, for example:

```
Product ID | Translation (Column name) 
58965        Yes 
58965        Yes  
58965        No
```

I would like to keep only the first two rows and remove the last row with the condition, Translation = No from the example shown above. How can I write that?

Thank you, all!

Comment: try doing something like this: `df.loc[df.groupby('Product ID').cumcount().lt(2)]`

Comment: @rhug123 Your answer is correct. Do you want to put it as an answer?

Comment: sure ill do that

Comment: Thank you @rhug123 - since the dupes are not in order, I forgot to mention that in addition, I would like to keep at least one from those dupes the ones that have a value 'No' from column 'Translation' - how would I write that in your answer?  df.loc[df.groupby('Product ID').cumcount().lt(2)]

Comment: In your edit with `Translation` column, the last row is with `No`.  So you still want to remove the last row ?

Comment: @SeaBean Thank you - in that case, I would not want to remove that last row, but we can remove one of the other two - since both have a 'yes' under translation column

Comment: You want to keep every row with Translation = No, or just keep one of them ?

Comment: Actually, I do not want to keep the Translation = No - how do I write that keep all the product ID duplicates, except the ones that have Translation = No? Ty @SeaBean

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Product ID').cumcount().lt(2)]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, however, since the dupes are not in order, I forgot to mention that in addition, I would like to keep at least one from those dupes the ones that have a value 'No' from column 'Translation' - how would I write that in your answer? df.loc[df.groupby('Product ID').cumcount().lt(2)] – Thanks again! @rhug123

Comment: would adding  `df = df.sort_values('Translation')` before the answer provided above give you what youre looking for?

Comment: Actually, I do not want to keep the Translation = No - how do I write that keep all the product ID duplicates, except the ones that have Translation = No? Ty @rhug123

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think you can use `drop_duplicates()` to solve this problem. I'd say use a counter and when the count for a "Product ID" exceeds 2, start setting them to `NaN`, then you can use `df.dropna()` at the end.

Something like:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

c = Counter()
for index, row in df:
    pid = row['Product ID']
    c[pid] += 1
    if c[pid] > 2:
        df.loc[index, 'Product ID'] = np.nan

df.dropna(inplace=True)
```